# Why are my Bootstrap margins different sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone please explain why my left margin is a different size that the right?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <button class="tab-button tab-yellow">One</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <button class="tab-button tab-green">Two</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <button class="tab-button tab-blue">Three</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phpMick/e51t1fs8/

Thanks,

Mick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must encapsulate a `div` inside the button and use the `margin`. If you do it from the outside, you move the outline of the `col- *`. It is best in these elements to put them inside a `<div>` and to excuse a class

EXAMPLE

HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <div class="margin">
         <button class="tab-button tab-yellow">One</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.tab-button {

    border: none;
    color: #080906;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 32px;
    border-radius: 8px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.margin{
      margin: 10px 25px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e51t1fs8/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Also tested on tablet, which is where I need it.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is your custom left margin on the buttons of 25px, is pushing the button "too far" outside the Bootstrap column. It would be better to use a margin like this..

`margin: 10px auto;`

http://www.codeply.com/go/DvflVK1ypd

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct. The answer I accepted also takes these margins out of the buttons. Thanks.